# Using derived abstract classes to define different logic used by Model

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, abstract

I am currently setting up an architecture that should allow me to set up multiple derived classes of an abstract base class. These classes will implement the actual logic of the methods and assign values to the properties.

I have a model that should implement a specific logic from the respecting class, depending on a property.

```
public abstract class AbstractLogic
{
    protected String Prop1 { get; set; }
    public abstract String Method1();
}


public class ActualLogic : AbstractLogic
    {
        public ActualLogic()
        {
           Prop1 = "Test";
        }

        public override string Method1()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }

public class Model
{
    public string LogicType { get; set; }
    private AbstractLogic Logic { get; set; } //I need to have something like this to use the logic inside of the model
}
```

I want to use the classes in a generic way, for example calling `Model.logic.Method1()` somewhere and it should pull the logic from the `ActualLogic` class

My problem with this architecture is that when I load the `Model`, the `Logic` property is always `null` and thus working with it is very hard and it feels inconsistent.

I can't really wrap my head around a better solution, so maybe someone can help me with this. Maybe an interface would be better? Or a generic class? I tried both, but couldn't get a better result.

Thank you in advance.

**Edit**

Moved my own answer to an answer.

Comment: No need for generics here, since the abstract class already defines the interface your model should work with. What you do need is to instantiate your `Logic` property before you can use it.

Comment: Add a constructor in your model to initialize it - `public Model() { Logic = new ActualLogic(); }`

Comment: There is no instance created for ActualLogic,  


Logic = new ActualLogic(); in the constructor of Model

Comment: Answers go in the answer section, not the question

Answer (score 0):

I found an even better way to access the right logic class:
In my Model, I define a property enum LogicType and just access the respecting LogicClass using an extension method.

```
public enum LogicType
    {
        actuallogic,
        actuallogic2
    }

    public static class LogicExtensions
    {
        public static AbstractLogic LogicClass(this LogicType self)
        {
            switch (self)
            {
                case LogicType.actuallogic:
                    return new ActualLogic();
                case LogicType.actuallogic2:
                    return new ActualLogic2();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I can access it like this `Model.LogicType.LogicClass()`